# Request to reopen question because closed as too broad

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

this is the first time I'm in meta, so I don't really know how it work but but one of you suggesting me to ask this on meta

I want to reopen my question [is there any famous doujinshi artist?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8051/is-there-any-famous-doujinshi-artist) but it close as too broad, I already tried to make it not too broad by adding this

> Maybe not world wide but national wide?

but apparently it's not enough, how can I make this question not too broad?

Thanks for your concern

Comment: The scope of possible answers to your question is quite broad. It's like asking are there any self-published independant music artist that are famous nationally? It depends on the genre and audience. Some people might have heard of them while others haven't. What you need is something gauge them by (like in an award ceremony). E.g. best selling artist, most listened downloaded, most talked about in X year/quarter.

Comment: As what @Krazer has said you might want to define what genre and audience yoiur looking at but also if you happen to be refering original doujin or doujin based off an existsing series, if the latter you might want to define the series cause a well known Yuru Yuri doujin circle may be unknown because they are eclypsed by Madoka dujin circle.

Comment: zargin also said in his comment, maybe you could ask about those who became well know enough they decided to go pro limiting answers to say the past decade or so, from what i remember Type-Moon was originally a doujin circle

Answer (score 4):

Think about your questions for a moment, you're asking us "Who are the famous dojinshi artists?". How do you define "famous"? How "famous" is "famous"? Do you want the top 5? top 10? top 1000?

That's why it's **too broad**, you need to scope your question down only to the practical parts, ask a clear question that can be given a clear answer. Right now, there can't be a clear answer to your question.

If you think there can, please refine your requirements. Right now, your question is *still* too broad.